# Trouble extracting data from Gmail to Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I need to extract specific data from Gmail into a spreadsheet.

So far I've been able to more or less tweak it to my needs, but one big problem is that it only extracts the data from the first email on any thread. The emails in question are booking confirmations for tours, so Gmail will automatically group them together under one thread (if they are for the same day). I disabled Gmail conversation view feature, and even though on my inbox each email is separate, when I run the code, it still adds only the data from the first email of each thread to my sheet. Any ideas?

This is the code:

```js
function gather() {
    let messages = getGmail();

    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    messages.forEach(message => {curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message))});
}

function getGmail() {
    const query = "from:fake@faketours.com NOT label:done";

    let threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("done");
    if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel("done")}

    let messages = [];

    threads.forEach(thread => {
        messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
        label.addToThread(thread);
    });

    return messages;
}

function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/,/g,'')
    .replace(/.+[a-z]:/ig,',')
    .replace(/Hey team/g,'')
    .replace(/.+-/g,'')
    .replace(/.+!/,'')
    .replace(/^,/,'')
    .split(',');

    let result = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(index => parsed[index]);

    return result;
    }
```

Comment: While links to external content might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained, meaning that besides the link, the relevant parts of the external content should be added into the question. In this specific case it looks that he external content is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue and solution:

- For each thread, you are only getting the first message: `thread.getMessages()[0]`.
- Instead, you should iterate through all message threads and push all its bodies to your `messages` array.

#### Modifications:

Replace this:

```
threads.forEach(thread => {
    messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
    label.addToThread(thread);
});
```

With this:

```
threads.forEach(thread => {
    const threadMessages = thread.getMessages().map(m => m.getPlainBody());
    messages.push(...threadMessages);
    label.addToThread(thread);
});
```

#### Reference:

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)